# Netty channelRead not getting full message

Tags: java, netty

Why doesn't channelRead() give me the full message I send to the server? Fragmentation sometimes occur when messages are getting above 140 bytes (Roughly, sometimes more and sometimes less). I'm using a TCP socket using the NioServerSocketChannel class.

I'm using 4.1.0.Beta5.

Isn't there a way to read the full message when it has arrived?

```
this.serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
this.serverBootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(1), new NioEventLoopGroup(6))
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
                    {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new TestServerHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, (int)Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, (int) Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
this.serverBootstrap.bind(this.host, this.port);
```

And class TestServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        String s = buffer.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            s = s.replace("[" + ((char)i) + "]", i + "");
        }

        System.out.println(s.length() + "");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

I need a way to get the full bytebuf / bytearray when it has fully arrived at the server and get notified of that so my application can respond in a correct way according to the data the client has send.

So in short: How can I prevent fragmentation and have the channelRead event output the whole message / bytebuf.

Comment: from a quick glance at the code I would say you are not doing anything with the msg `Object` in `channelRead()` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic data type used by Netty is Channel Buffers or ByteBuf. This is simply a collection of bytes and nothing else. In your code you have simply used a custom handler to handle the raw incoming data. This is generally not a good practice. A very basic netty pipeline should look something like the following

[image]

So a pipeline consists of a decoder / encoder and then we have our custom handlers or logging handlers. We never really handle any raw data as is. TCP is a stream protocol. It does not identify when a specific packet ends and a new packet starts. Even if we send a very very large packet or say two individual packets, they will simply be treated as a set of bytes and when we try to read the raw set of bytes, **fragmentation** might happen.

So properly implement a channel pipeline which consists of a String decoder / encoder (whatever you need) and this problem will go away.

Comment: If the a packet gets split into multiple packets / ByteBuf's, I don't know what belongs to what due to the client nature (Which I cannot modify). The client sends the data as one packet and does no splitting.

Say two long packets get split somewhere in the middle, I cannot identify what second part belongs to a packet.

Comment: @Wesley That is true. You cannot possibly know as to which set of bytes belong to what packet. One possible solution is that you add some delimiter to identify the ending of packet yourself. But as you say, that is not possible. However, on using encoder for this scenario, Netty would handle these issues for you. You just need to send the packet and when it crosses the Netty pipeline and reaches your custom handler, it will be a complete packet.

Comment: @Wesley please refer to this Git repo. https://github.com/edorado93/StringDecoding

Comment: @Wesley in case this works for you, please accept the answer so that other readers can benefit from this. :)

Answer (score 1):

TCP provides a stream of bytes, so you can't rely on receiving a complete message in one packet. You will need a handler in your pipeline that knows how your messages are framed. Netty provides some built-in handlers that you can adapt for your protocol. See [Dealing with a Stream-based Transport](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-11) in the Netty User Guide.