# Netty4 readableBytes is too small

Tags: java, netty

I get the exception when decode with Netty4. the message's length only 640, but the readableBytes is not enough.

```
 06-19 21:45:13.150 4192-4233/com.seewo.remote V/RemoteMassageDecoder: Decoder messageType == 1, messageLength: 640
 06-19 21:45:13.152 4192-4233/com.seewo.remote E/exceptionCaught: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.Exception: readableBytes is too small
```

1、First,add decoder in ChannelInitializer

```
private static final int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = 1024 * 1024;
private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH = 4;
private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET = 1;
private static final int LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT = 2;
private static final int INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP = 0;
channelPipeline.addLast("decoder", new RemoteMassageDecoder(MAX_FRAME_LENGTH,
                LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH, LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET, LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT, INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP));
channelPipeline.addLast("encoder", new RemoteMessageEncoder());
```

2、second,decoder the bytes from server

```
@Override
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    byte startCharacter = in.readByte();
    int messageLength = in.readInt();
    byte messageType = in.readByte();
    in.readByte();
    Log.v("RemoteMassageDecoder", "startCharacter == " + (startCharacter & 0xff));
    Log.v("RemoteMassageDecoder", "Decoder messageType == " + messageType + ", messageLength: " + messageLength);
    if (messageLength < 0) {
        throw new Exception("messageLength < 0");
    }
    if (messageLength == 0 || messageType == 0) {
        in.readByte();
        return null;
    }
    if (in.readableBytes() < messageLength) {
        throw new Exception("readableBytes is too small");
    }
    byte[] content = new byte[messageLength];
    in.readBytes(content);
    byte stopCharacter = in.readByte();
    if (startCharacter != START_CHARACTER || stopCharacter != STOP_CHARACTER) {
        return null;
    }
    return ProtocolPack.parseFrom(AESHelper.decryptContent(content));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netty channelRead not getting full message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327443/netty-channelread-not-getting-full-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is simple: you can't expect the TCP stream will always return enough data at the same time.

The solution is also simple: Your ChannelHandler can just extends ReplyingDecoder which can help you handle underlying steam properly.